# (Rust) Implementing a trait generically for another trait

Tags: rust, traits

I have two traits, `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo` describing different kinds of objects. Both implement `Sized` so they are not object-safe (I cannot implement for `dyn TypeOne` or `dyn TypeTwo`). I also have a third trait `Hashable` which I would like to implement for both `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo`.

```
pub trait Hashable {
    fn hash(&self) -> &str;
}

pub trait TypeOne { }

pub trait TypeTwo { }

impl<T: TypeOne> Hashable for T {
    fn hash(&self) -> &str {
        todo!();
    }
}

impl<T: TypeTwo> Hashable for T {
    fn hash(&self) -> &str {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

The above code gives a conflicting implementations error, which I fully understand. If a struct were to implement both `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo` it would have two different (i.e. conflicting) implementations.

From my understanding after asking a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351603/implementing-mul-for-a-generic-struct), there is a way to circumvent this limitation when the traits are defined within the same crate (see @kmdreko's response). Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick preferred implementation on conflicting trait implementation (using negative bounds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131776/pick-preferred-implementation-on-conflicting-trait-implementation-using-negativ)

Comment: It only works in the related question because the `BIG` implementation is with a concrete type that is known to not conflict. That does not extend to implementing the trait on a generic type. Generics are not constrained to types only within your crate.

Comment: Are you just trying to do a dynamic dispatch based on a choice of "algorithm" for hash ?

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm not sure negative bounds will work because in that example they are implementing negative bounds on a concrete type u32 instead of trait but I will play around with it a little more.

Comment: @AhmedMasud previously I had "trait TypeOne: Hashable" but each concrete instantiation of these traits has the same hash function using internal methods of the trait (not shown for simplicity). I was hoping there was a way to generically implement this rather than requiring concrete implementations.

Comment: @gormatron3000 yeah that doesn't work :'( — because without the concrete type the compiler has lost the information about which one to select.